# Wait for method within loop to complete before looping again

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, recursion, javafx

I'm building a java fx app and have a while loop on its own thread , but the loop doesnt wait for the Dijkstra method to return an array, I seem to have temporarily fixed the problem by sleeping the thread for 1000ms and I don't really know why that is working but is there a better approach where I can wait for the method to complete then start the next iteration?

```
    public class Chasers {

    public volatile List<List<Integer>>  Path; ///////

   volatile int ChaserX;
   volatile int ChaserY;
   volatile int PlayerX;
   volatile int PlayerY;

   boolean Continue=true;


volatile int  PathSize = 0;
int dir = 5;
volatile int i=0;
Main MainPassed=new Main();
DijkstraSolve PathFinder = new DijkstraSolve();

  Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {

        @Override protected Void call() throws Exception {

            while (Continue) {
                i = 0;
                width = MainPassed.width;
                ChaserX = ((int) (PlayerIns.chaser.getCenterX() / width) * width);
                ChaserY = ((int) (PlayerIns.chaser.getCenterY() / width) * width);
                PlayerX = ((int) (PlayerIns.player.getCenterX() / width) * width);
                PlayerY = ((int) (PlayerIns.player.getCenterY() / width) * width);
                Path = PathFinder.Dijkstra(ChaserX, ChaserY, PlayerX, PlayerY, MainPassed);//wait for this to return??
                PathSize = Path.size() - 1;

            }

            return null;
        }
    };
    Thread th = new Thread(task);
    //th.setDaemon(true);
    th.start();



     public void MoveChaser(Player PlayerIns){
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(50), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println(" current path "+Path);
            System.out.println("==============================");



        }
    }));
    timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);

    timeline.play();
}
```

}

Comment: Is `Dijkstra()` run in a new thread as well? if not, the loop does wait for it to finish. Why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: Just runs in the same thread which its called from, it just keeps continuously  calling it though without it finishing.

Comment: I see in the comment below you are using UI. This is probably where the problem is, it takes sometime to update. The loop *does* wait for `Dijkstra()` to finish.

Comment: Not doing any ui updates on the thread . Really weird then

Comment: Could it be that it takes time to retrieve ui updates that's only interaction it has with the ui , because you're right the method is completing . However the as soon as I put thread.sleep in it works ?? makes no sense

Comment: If `Dijkstra` does not just schedule the calculation on a seperate thread, the method always returns after the computation is completed. I'm not sure what you want to wait for there anyways. Also how are updates done (ui updates as well as "input"=player/chaser position updates)?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.
Unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them. That said: you _must not_ modify the scenegraph off the fx application thread.

Comment: Tryin to make a mre, I updated the post a bit , so basically yeah @fabian it returns the array properly turns out thats not the issue , its that when I  try to access path from the timline below it returns an empty array? But when I add thread.sleep on the task thread , path is no longer empty and I get the correct non empty array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are busy-looping and potentially starving the UI thread.
You haven't shown how the variables are declared. (And you are using a non-standard naming convention that is contributing to the confusion.  Please don't name variables with capital letters so they look like classes.)

Perhaps the Path variable (with should be named 'path') is not declared volatile?

Comment: yeah I set the 'path' field to volatile but no luck:(

Comment: Could you edit the question to state what is actually happening vs what you want to happen?  We have already established that the loop is (has to be) waiting for the  Dijkstra method to return.  What are the types of the variables etc.?  What is 'Path'?

Comment: Path is just a 2d array of coordinates. Then I would like to access this from the timeline but it's always empty ,  but when Path is printed from within the thread it is not empty and is correct.

Comment: it's like outside of the thread  'Path' isnt seeing the modification

Comment: You aren't showing enough code.  You are saying that 'Path' is a 2d array of coordinates, but an array would only print as an object reference in the code you have shown, so you would not be able to tell if it was empty or not.  We can't see enough of the program to find the problem.

Comment: Are you seeing in the Timeline event that Path is being replaced with a new array instance at all?

Comment: No i'm not seeing that lol , where does it do that? It's an arrayList which might be why its not printing as an object reference. I'll try to add more code but the Dijsktra method is pretty long

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198798/discussion-between-swpalmer-and-fred).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using the `join()` method, this method when called from the parent thread makes parent thread wait till child thread terminates. Use `th.join()` after `th.start()`. Your task should run between the execution of these two commands.

Read up on [multithreading basics](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/03/multithreading-in-java/) and the [Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join--).

Comment: Thanks , gave it a go , the ui freezes up ?, i'll keep fiddling with it

Comment: It freezes because Continue is always true , so the child thread never terminates I think

Comment: Because of the nature of the JavaFX application thread, using `join` is not an option, even if the thread completes in finite time. The application thread must not be blocked for extended amounts of time (several ms) to avoid the ui from freezing. The tutorial linked does not contain any additional info that would help in this case either (and even if it did, we'd need to consider this a link-only answer).

Comment: "fiddling" is the road to disaster in multithreading. Developing an understanding and a clear concept is the only alternative. You should also avoid low-level threading features if possible.